# Import names in ELF binary

Tags: linux, import, dllimport, file-format, elf

Where does the ELF format stores the names of imported functions? Is it always possible to enumerate all import names, like for PE executables?

For example, if a binary is using `printf` is it possible to tell it does, just by static analysis of the binary itself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In ELF they're called undefined symbols.  You can view the list of undefined symbols by:

- `nm -D <file>|grep -w U`
- `objdump -T <file>|grep "\*UND\*"`

ELF files don't specify which symbols come from which libraries; it just adds a list of shared libraries to link to into the ELF binary, and lets the linker find the symbols in the libraries.

Comment: cannot we get from which shared library we got those functions?

Comment: Note that a defined symbol can be imported as well. You need to look at the relocation tables to see which symbols are used.

Comment: @AnwarMohamed: no because they are not tied to a specific shared library in ELF.