# Linux ELF file: How to get the shared object belonging to an imported function

Tags: shared-libraries, elf, dynamic-linking, objdump, ldd

Given a dynamically linked ELF binary, say for example `/bin/less`.

Inside the binary, there is a call to a function provided by a shared library, for example `strcpy()`

How can I find out from which shared library/shared object the `strcp` function is obtained? 
In other words, I want to get pairs func_name/shared_obj_name.so.

Answering [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10480657/import-names-in-elf-binary), Michael Slade wrote:

> ELF files don't specify which symbols come from which libraries; it
>   just adds a list of shared libraries to link to into the ELF binary,
>   and lets the linker find the symbols in the libraries.

Yet there must be a way to gather the required info (using the linker). Executing the binary and ltrace-ing it is not an option in my case. What I tried so far:

I tried `objdump -T /bin/less | grep strcpy` which gives me:

```
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 strcpy
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.3.4 __strcpy_chk
```

This is neither unambigious nor does it give me the name of a `.so` file.

Running `ldd /bin/less`, returning:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe8b7fa000)
libtinfo.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007f92c23a5000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f92c1fe0000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f92c25ec000))
```

lets me think that the "GLIBC_2.2.5" corresponds to `libc.so.6`

How can I programmatically find the corresponding shared object (.so file) to an (imported) function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I find out from which shared library/shared object the strcp function is obtained?

In general you can't: that library can change at runtime. For example, if I compile the following source:

```
int strcpy(char *a, const char *src) { abort(); }

$ gcc -fPIC -shared -o foo.so foo.c
```

and then run your program like so:

```
LD_PRELOAD=./foo.so /bin/less
```

then the library from which `strcpy` is obtained is `foo.so`. Using `LD_PRELOAD` this way is called library interpositioning, and is useful in all kinds of [circumstances](http://www.drdobbs.com/building-library-interposers-for-fun-and/184404926).

There are other ways to *inject* a different library into the process besides `LD_PRELOAD`.

If you are *not* using any such mechanisms, and are using GLIBC, then you can ask the dynamic loader to answer that question for you. Here is one way:

```
 LD_DEBUG=bindings ldd -r /bin/less < /dev/null |& egrep '\Wstrcpy\W'
     26623: binding file /bin/bash [0] to /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `strcpy' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
     26633: binding file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 [0] to /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `strcpy' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
     26633: binding file /bin/less [0] to /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `strcpy' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
```

Above you can see that `ldd` invokes `bash` and `less` as separate processes, and both of them bind to `libc.so.6` for this particular symbol.

> How can I programmatically find the corresponding shared object (.so file) to an (imported) function?

If you are using GLIBC, use [dladdr](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dladdr.3.html) to "ask" the dynamic linker. Returned "info" argument will tell you the filename.